xlsxio do not allow to write to the file that are have been read before
Problem is if I read file for example test.xlsx using xlsxioreader C library and after that I immidietly trying to write into this file Im getting an error:
$ ./a
Sheetname: Sheet1
Read value: dasf
zip_close failed (2,13)
can't close zip archive : Renaming temporary file failed: Permission denied

Workbook looks like below

        Sheet1         
| -------- | -------- |
| dasf     |          |
|          |          |

So there is only 'dasf' string in A1 cell of 'Sheet1' worksheet.
I want wokbook to look like

           1         
| -------- | -------- |
| test1    |          |
| test2    | test3    |

Code below
#include <xlsxio_write.h>
#include <xlsxio_read.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{  
    xlsxiowriter writeHandle;

    xlsxioreader readHandle;
    xlsxioreadersheetlist sheetlist;
    xlsxioreadersheet sheet;    

    const char* sheetname;
    char *value;

    //--------------------------------------------------- Read

    if ((readHandle = xlsxioread_open("test.xlsx")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error open .xlsx file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((sheetlist = xlsxioread_sheetlist_open(readHandle)) != NULL)
    {
        sheetname = xlsxioread_sheetlist_next(sheetlist);
        printf("Sheetname: %s\n", sheetname);
    }

    if ((sheet = xlsxioread_sheet_open(readHandle, sheetname, XLSXIOREAD_SKIP_EMPTY_ROWS)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error open sheet\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    xlsxioread_sheet_next_row(sheet);

    if ((value = xlsxioread_sheet_next_cell(sheet)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Read null\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Read value: %s\n", value);
        xlsxioread_free(value);
    }
    xlsxioread_sheet_close(sheet);
    xlsxioread_close(readHandle);

    //--------------------------------------------------- Write

    if ((writeHandle = xlsxiowrite_open("test.xlsx", "1")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating .xlsx file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    xlsxiowrite_add_cell_string(writeHandle, "test1");
    xlsxiowrite_next_row(writeHandle);

    xlsxiowrite_add_cell_string(writeHandle, "test2");
    xlsxiowrite_add_cell_string(writeHandle, "test3");

    xlsxiowrite_close(writeHandle);

    return 0;
}

I've tried to wait some time before open file second time for writing by using sleep() function.

Maybe you need to call xlsxioread_sheet_close() before calling xlsxioread_close().

@pmacfarlane unfortunately did not help

thank you anyway, I found that it's necessary to close sheetlist also:
code
xlsxioread_sheet_close(sheet);
xlsxioread_sheetlist_close(sheetlist);
xlsxioread_close(readHandle);
code

To solve this problem I just closed worksheet and worksheet list before closing workbook:
xlsxioread_sheet_close(sheet);
xlsxioread_sheetlist_close(sheetlist);
xlsxioread_close(readHandle);

